# Scroll - Hide Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm searching for a way to `Hide` the content when scrolled. Let me explain.

This from the [Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/library) Website:

Normal Content:

[image]

When Scrolled:

[image]

As you see the content *hides* and the line appears. Go Check it out [here](http://teamtreehouse.com/library)

Has anybody an Idea how they did this?

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: I'm asking how they achieved this Style, that the scrolling hides the content and slides into this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because on scroll down of div

They are adding a class `shadowy` to a

`<div class="heading-pocket"></div>`

```
     .heading-pocket.shadowy {
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); //cause of the shadow on top
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
    }
```

On scrolling back to top they are removing the class `shadowy`

Comment: They are adding the class via JS right? could you give me an example of the code ?

Comment: This link would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll

Comment: Helped a lot !! Thanks @Sanjeev

Answer (score -3):

It's called CSS. You want position:fixed on whatever "header" you want to overlay the content.

Comment: I actually didn't down voted you. I know it's CSS Tyler, but this specific Styling of the Scroll Hide is pretty awesome and i'm searching for a way to replicate it / and learn.

Comment: I agree the styling is very cool. If utilized right it can work wonders... Except it's rather over used now since bootstrap specifically uses this in its navbars. I can't speak for the other frameworks but position:fixed is nice. Use it almost as use would an absolute positioned element using the top, left, right, bottom elements

Comment: I'm not talking about the position, i'm talking about the Transition happening when scrolling.