# CSS Jquery Drop Down Menu Button Click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a basic Jquery drop down menu that activates the button according to where you are on the page?  So after I scroll, the menu will drop down without a button click, it will drop based on where my screen is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window scrolltop for this if I am reading the question right here is another stackoverflow question similar to this [Add/remove class with jquery based on vertical scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll)

You would use somthing like

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //either use window below or replace window with the element you want to toggle    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    //set the value from the top where you want to code to execute
    if (scroll >= 500) {
        //your toggle code here
    } else {
        //your untoggle code here for scrolling back up
    }
});
```