# Ember – Add class on scroll to top

Tags: jquery, css, ember.js

I’m trying to create a sticky header in an ember application. I just want to add a class to the `<div id="stickyHeader"></div>` via jquery when the user starts scrolling on the page. I squeezed the jquery into an action, but nothing happens...

I’m more a designer than a developer so pretty sure I oversee something fundametal here.

I have a `<div></div>` like this in my *applications.hbs*:

```
<div id="stickyHeader">
... some content ...
</div>
```

and an action in *application.js*:

```
...
actions: {
stickyHeaderClass: function(){
  this(window).scroll('addClassOnScroll')    
      var scroll = this(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= 5) {
          return Ember.$('#stickyHeader').addClass('active');
      } else {
          return Ember.$('#stickyHeader').removeClass('active');
      }
},
....
```

I crapped the jquery stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll#answer-12558348). The rest is copy and paste ...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create component for this functionality or use relevant add-on, and here is quick working [prototype done in ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/0be411abf445bfbc5664?openFiles=styles.app.css%2Capplication.template.hbs)

you can copy that component and use it like

```
{{#sticky-header}}
 sticky content
{{/sticky-header}}
```