# How to change navbar-default to navbar-inverse on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At the top of my website, the main navigation class is:

```
navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bg
```

I am trying to make it so when you scroll, the class changes to so I can create a more elegant and easier scroll animation:

```
navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bg
```

How is this accomplished with Javascript? I can't find ANYTHING on the internet...the one thing I did find let you remove one class but doesn't work because I have like 10 different classes at once...

Comment: Really? Nothing on the internet? There should be thousands out there.. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Look into jquery, like `.scrollTop()` and then just add or remove the class based on what the scroll value is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/remove class with jquery based on vertical scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll)

Comment: @choz no, that won't work because of the 5 classes I have. I tried that before.

Comment: @XanderLuciano I have tried, but it usually just messes up the whole page :/

Comment: That will work.. You just have invalid selector.. Do me a favor and dig this up `$('navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.bg').removeClass('navbar-default').addClass('navbar-inverse')`..

Comment: Tried it. Does nothing. The class doesn't remove at all. @choz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

Use `$(window).scroll()` and `addClass()` to add the bg class to your nav when you scroll down past a certain point. *Note that `addClass` and `removeClass` allow you to add/remove individual class names from tags where multiple classes exist.*

Note that you will probably need to use `!important` to force the color change -- bootstrap can be tenacious.

```js
var viz=true, win = $(window), nav=$('nav');

win.scroll(function(){

    pos = win.scrollTop();
  
    if ( viz && pos > 100 ){
      viz = false;
      nav.addClass('bg');
    }else if ( !viz && pos < 100 ){
      viz = true;
      nav.removeClass('bg');
    }

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 2000px;
}
.bg{background:green !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```