# Adding Javascript crashes site (Wordpress, Customizr child theme)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, scroll, dom-events

I'm trying to amend the header on [this site](http://cluster4.website-staging.uk/simplyfloors.co.uk/) which is currently in a test environment.

The intention is to amend the header when the user scrolls down the page by toggling between two classes. Details are below - the issue I'm having is that adding in the JS code to my child theme's `functions.php` file is causing the site to crash. The only way I'm able to retrieve access to the Wordpress admin panel (and have the site appear in the browser again) is by overwriting the child theme's `functions.php` with a previous version using the FTP. Any help would be gratefully received.

## **CSS** (trimmed to relevant parts)

```
.header-widget-shortheader {
  color: #08c;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1066px) {
.header-widget {
  color: #08c;
  padding-right: 30px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -80px !important;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1065px) {
.header-widget {
  color: #08c;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: -0px !important;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 960px) {
.header-widget {
  color: #08c;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: -0px !important;
}
}
```

## **Javascript**

I'm trying to add in the following. Please do advise if there's a better way of doing this (due to the problem I'm having, I've not actually seen how it will perform yet).

```
window.onscroll = function() {headerWidgetPlacement()};
function headerWidgetPlacement() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("myP").className = "header-widget-shortheader";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myP").className = "header-widget";
    }
}
```

I'm intending to apply both classes to the widget, with this code intended to toggle on `.header-widget-shortheader` when scrolling beyond 50px and then revert back to `.header-widget` when scrolling back up again. In other words, for just one code to be active depending on how far down the screen the user has scrolled.

## **My existing child theme's functions.php**

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

//----- Amend footer credits -----//

add_filter('tc_credits_display', 'my_custom_credits', 20);
function my_custom_credits(){ 
$credits = '10 The Triangle, Kingston, Surrey, KT1 3RT';
$newline_credits = 'Website development by Max Rice';
return '
<div class="span6 credits">
                    <p> &middot; &copy; '.esc_attr( date( 'Y' ) ).' <a href="'.esc_url( home_url() ).'" title="'.esc_attr(get_bloginfo()).'" rel="bookmark">'.esc_attr(get_bloginfo()).'</a> &middot; '.($credits ? $credits : 'Designed by <a href="http://www.presscustomizr.com/">Press Customizr</a>').' &middot;'.($newline_credits ? '<br />&middot; '.$newline_credits.' &middot;' : '').'</p>       </div>';
}

// -----Adds widget to header and positions----- //

// Adds a widget area.
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Extra Header Widget Area',
    'id' => 'extra-widget-area',
    'description' => 'Extra widget area in the header',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget extra-header-widget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2>',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ));
}
// Place the widget area after the header
add_action ('__after_logo', 'add_my_widget_area', 10);
function add_my_widget_area() {
  if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('Extra Header Widget Area');
  }
}

// ------ITEMS BELOW ARE STILL IN TEST------ //

// -----Add secondary menu----- //

add_action( 'init', 'register_secondary_menu' ); // this registers your menu with WP
function register_secondary_menu() {
    if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menu' ) ) {
        register_nav_menu( 'secondary-menu', 'Secondary Menu' );
    }
}

// Select the add_action you need, depending on where you want to add the menu and disable the rest:
// add_action('__before_header', 'display_secondary_menu');     // use this line to add above header
add_action('__header', 'display_secondary_menu', 1000, 0);     // use this to add after header
// add_action('__before_footer', 'display_secondary_menu');     // use this line to add above footer
// add_action('wp_footer', 'display_secondary_menu', 1000, 0);     // use this to add before credits

// display function for your menu:
function display_secondary_menu() {
    echo ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary-menu' ) ? wp_nav_menu (
        array (
            'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu',
            'container_id'    => 'secondary-menu',
            'container_class'    => 'secondary-menu'
        )
    ).'
' : '' );
}
```

Comment: Where is your script - in your header, external file, ... ?

Comment: With jQuery so easily available in WP, I'd suggest using that - in that way you can **add classes** and remove them, instead of completely replacing them.

Comment: What exactly crashes? Debug please

Comment: Most importantly to answer your question - what does **causing the site to crash** mean? What happens? Are there errors? Do you have WP_DEBUG turned on in your config file?

Comment: And a small tip: calling a function in the event handler is unecessary just do window.onscroll=function(){code of headerWidgetPlacement}

Comment: @cale_b, I'm inserting the script into my child theme's `functions.php` file. Would using jQuery avoid this crash problem? By 'crash', I mean nothing loads in the browser - just a white screen in Firefox or a load error (no specifics) in Chrome.

@Jonasw: Error log as follows:
`AH01215: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/cluster-sites/4/s/simplyfloors.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/functions.php on line 45: /home/cluster-sites/4/s/simplyfloors.co.uk/public_html/index.php`

Comment: @cale_b, I just tried implementing the jQuery solution I found in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll) (third piece of code in highest ranking answer) and again it crashed and I had to re-upload the `functions.php`.

Comment: So - #1 - you need to [turn on WP_DEBUG](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/debugging-wordpress-how-to-use-wp_debug/) so the error gets outputted to the screen (turn it OFF once you're done developing).  #2 - the error you posted above **explains the whole problem** - can you show us which line is 45 in your code above?  I'm not seeing an `=` in your function code, but I could be missing it.

Comment: @cale_b, the error is caused by the opening line: `$(function() {`
However, I stuck the code into Dreamweaver and it's telling me there's an error on the second `var header = $(".header-widget");`, third `$(window).scroll(function() {` and fourth `var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();` lines as well.

Comment: I should note that's using the jQuery option instead. i.e.: `$(function() {
    var header = $(".header-widget");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            header.removeClass('header-widget').addClass("header-widget-shortheader");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("header-widget-shortheader").addClass('header-widget');
        }
    });
});`