# Sticky column vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a grid to dispose the contents in a specific way and I need to make one of the columns to scroll vertically follwing the long text that I have on the left column when the distance to the top is 0.

On my `CSS`, I've tried the `position: sticky;`, but is not working.

I've also tried to put a `jQuery` solution with `var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
Stickyfill.add(sidebar);` but nothing.

I'm missing something?

Thank you

```css
.grid1{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.grade2{
  display: inline;
}

.grid3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 43% 57%;
}

.column-1-1 { 
float: left; 
width: 45%;
background: red;
}

.column-1-2 { 
float: right; 
width: 53%; 
background: red;
}

.column-2-1 { 
float: left; 
width: 18%;
background: blue;
}

.column-2-2 { 
float: left; 
width: 67%;
background: blue;
margin-left: 15px;
}

.column-2-3 { 
float: right; 
width: 11%; 
background: blue;
}
    
.column-3-1 { 
grid-column:1;
grid-row: 1;
background: green;
}

.column-3-2 { 
grid-column:2;
grid-row: 1;
background: green;
}

.column-3-3 { 
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 3;
background: green;
margin-top: 15px;
grid-row: 2;
}

.info { 
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid1">
  <div class="column-1-1"><h6><strong>title1<hr></strong></h6></div>
  <div class="column-1-2"><h6><strong>title2<hr></strong></h6></div>
</div>
<div class="grid2">
  <div class="column-2-1"><p><strong>text</strong></p></div>
  <div class="column-2-3"><div class="info"><p><strong>infos</strong></p></div></div>   
  <div class="column-2-2">
     <div class="grid3">
        <div class="column-3-1">text</div>
        <div class="column-3-2">(LONG TEXT)</div>
        <div class="column-3-3">text</div>
     </div>
   </div>    
</div>
```

[image: Illustration]

Comment: I think you want position:fixed

Comment: position:sticky  works with coordonates, what have you tried and where didit fail ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I just made an edit showing what I've tried: CSS - position: sticky; top: 0;

Comment: Have you considered using a library for this? there are tons of good ones. There's also a native way, tho...

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge but i need to make it fix only after the distance to the top 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution with a `jQuery` code:

[Add/remove class with jquery based on vertical scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll)

```js
$(function() {
    var header = $(".info");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    
        if (scroll >= 90) {
            header.removeClass('info').addClass("info2");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("info2").addClass('info');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.grid1{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.grade2{
  display: inline;
}

.grid3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 43% 57%;
}

.column-1-1 { 
float: left; 
width: 45%;
background: red;
}

.column-1-2 { 
float: right; 
width: 53%; 
background: red;
}

.column-2-1 { 
float: left; 
width: 18%;
background: blue;
}

.column-2-2 { 
float: left; 
width: 67%;
background: blue;
margin-left: 15px;
}

.column-2-3 { 
float: right; 
width: 11%; 
background: blue;
}
    
.column-3-1 { 
grid-column:1;
grid-row: 1;
background: green;
}

.column-3-2 { 
grid-column:2;
grid-row: 1;
background: green;
}

.column-3-3 { 
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 3;
background: green;
margin-top: 15px;
grid-row: 2;
}

.info2 { 
position: fixed;
top: 0;
background:blue;
width: 11%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid1">
  <div class="column-1-1"><h6><strong>title1<hr></strong></h6></div>
  <div class="column-1-2"><h6><strong>title2<hr></strong></h6></div>
</div>
<div class="grid2">
  <div class="column-2-1"><p><strong>text</strong></p></div>
  <div class="column-2-3"><div class="info"><p><strong>infos</strong></p></div></div>   
  <div class="column-2-2">
     <div class="grid3">
        <div class="column-3-1">text</div>
        <div class="column-3-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis turpis augue, lacinia ut viverra ac, posuere et nisl. Cras ac erat arcu. Ut et neque vehicula massa viverra auctor. Praesent vehicula justo sit amet enim blandit scelerisque. Aenean ullamcorper vitae dolor non dignissim. Proin vulputate porta ante, nec posuere leo lobortis nec. Fusce id ante a erat tempus pulvinar. Suspendisse magna dolor, tincidunt at tristique a, dictum vel urna. Praesent vehicula justo sit amet enim blandit scelerisque. Aenean ullamcorper vitae dolor non dignissim. Proin vulputate porta ante, nec posuere leo lobortis nec. Fusce id ante a erat tempus pulvinar. Suspendisse magna dolor, tincidunt at tristique a, dictum vel urna.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis turpis augue, lacinia ut viverra ac, posuere et nisl. Cras ac erat arcu. Ut et neque vehicula massa viverra auctor. Praesent vehicula justo sit amet enim blandit scelerisque. Aenean ullamcorper vitae dolor non dignissim. Proin vulputate porta ante, nec posuere leo lobortis nec. Fusce id ante a erat tempus pulvinar. Suspendisse magna dolor, tincidunt at tristique a, dictum vel urna. Praesent vehicula justo sit amet enim blandit scelerisque. Aenean ullamcorper vitae dolor non dignissim. Proin vulputate porta ante, nec posuere leo lobortis nec. Fusce id ante a erat tempus pulvinar. Suspendisse magna dolor, tincidunt at tristique a, dictum vel urn
        </div>
        <div class="column-3-3">text</div>
     </div>
   </div>    
</div>
```