# How to add a class at specific section on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Hi I want to add a class at some specific section. to blur a image.

Reference : https://www.stanford.edu/ . I want to blur a image when user scroll to a section.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [ask] & [mcve].

Comment: duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll

Comment: No i want to find the section on scroll when scroll is in that section i want to add a class to that section so that i can blur the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add class when your **DIV** having image you want to blur is on the top or on some specific position on your page.

You have to get the dynamic scroll top of your **DIV** (Having image to be blur). Or you can say Offset in jQuery term.

```
    var YourDiv = $(".YourDivHavingImageToBeBlur");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        // Here You can add your conditions according to your requirments
        if (scroll == YourDiv.offset().top ) {
            YourDiv.addClass('YourClass');
        } 
    });
```

Comment: dua kar skta hun bhai pher

Comment: sahi bata bhai chal gea?

Comment: But there is an error of top undefined in the console.

  var YourDiv = $(".cheif");
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $('body').addClass('fixmenu');
    } else {
      $('body').removeClass('fixmenu');
    }
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Here You can add your conditions according to your requirments
    if (scroll >= YourDiv.offset().top - 280) {
      YourDiv.addClass('animated');
    }

  });