# Add/remove class/id to nav when scrolling to that posistion

Tags: javascript, jquery

right now i have this code to indicate on the nav links what id i am on.
But how can i also add a scroll function, if i scroll down to specific id then add the class to the right nav link. Thank you.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("nav.site-nav ul.open.desktop li a").click(function() {
        $('.current_yes').removeClass('current_yes');
        $(this).addClass("current_yes");
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    var url = window.location.href; 
    $('nav.site-nav ul.open.desktop li a').filter(function() {  
        return this.href == url;
    }).closest('a').addClass('current_yes');
});
```

and the nav look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="site-nav">
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="open desktop">
            <li><a id="link1" href="index.php#"><i class="site-nav--icon"></i>Hem</a></li>
            <li><a id="link2" href="index.php#products-anchor"><i class="site-nav--icon"></i>Produkter</a></li>
            <li><a id="link3" href="index.php#uthyres-anchor"><i class="site-nav--icon"></i>Uthyres</a></li>
            <li><a id="link4" href="#rent"><i class="site-nav--icon"></i>Kontakta</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The css for current link:

```
.current_yes {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #732813;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/remove class with jquery based on vertical scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll)

Comment: Tha's not working, all of links get class.