# How to add class when scroll down using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom, document

I want to add the class when the user scrolls down my page.

I tried this [stackoverflow answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558348/7734785), it is working only when the page load is not yet loaded completely.

I mean, When I refresh the page, I got the alert message from the following code as I expect, only when I scroll down before the page is completely loaded(which mean, the page is still loading).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();            
        if (scroll >= 100) {
            alert('scrolling is working');
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            alert("$(window).scrollTop() = " + $(window).scrollTop() + "   $(window).height()" + $(window).height() +  "");
        }
    })
})
```

> I am expecting, I should get the alert message after the page has completely loaded

**Note**

> I am not getting any alert after the page is completely loaded
>   One more thing, I am using mvc framework. I added javascript not on layout page. I gave my script link on `@RenderBody()` page

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k970jgmb/  Seems to work fine.

Comment: Why would you expect to get the alert message after the page is loaded? The first window scroll function will trigger the alert when you've scrolled down 100 pixels. The second only when you hit the bottom of the page.

Comment: @MikeS Actually I am trying to add image src attribute value when user scroll down. For testing, I am checking with alert. But I am not getting alert once page loaded completely