# Add and Remove class on window scroll

Tags: javascript

I read through a few other posts but am not finding anything similar to what I'm looking for. The code below works just fine but I'd like to add a delay when the class is added and removed until the page has scrolled a little bit since there is a header above the content. Any input is appreciated.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? fixGallery() : window.requestAnimationFrame(fixGallery);
});

function fixGallery() {
    var offsetTop = $('.cd-main-content').offset().top,
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    (scrollTop >= offsetTop) ? $('.cd-main-content').addClass('is-fixed') : $('.cd-main-content').removeClass('is-fixed');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an additional buffer to the `offsetTop` variable corresponding to the “delay” that you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, have you checked out this question? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll) [Possible Duplicate]

if you wish to add a delay, you can use `window.setTimeout()` to achieve that effect

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you! I'm not sure how I missed that!