# How can I change active class on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've managed to change the 'active' class 'on click', but can't figure out how to do so 'on scroll'. How can I change the 'active' class on scroll? Also, the links on the page that link to different sections on the page, how do I make it so the 'active' class is added to the corresponding 'li' item when I click to a specific section on the page?

Thanks in advance.

**CSS Style:**

```
nav.top-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;

    a.top-nav-logo-wrapper {
        padding-right: 2rem;
        // border: solid red 1px;

        img {
            width: 25rem;
        }
    }

    ul.top-nav-links {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding-left: 2rem;

        li {
            padding-top: .5rem;
            transition: .4s;

            &::after {
                content: "";
                display: block;
                width: 0;
                height: 2.5px;
                background: $clr-white;
                transition: width .3s;
            }

            &:hover::after {
                width: 100%;
                transition: width .3s;
            }

            a {
                font-size: 1.4rem;
                color: $clr-white;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: 400;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: .5rem;
                opacity: .9;
                transition: .4s;

                &:hover {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }

            &.active-desktop {
                opacity: 1;
                font-weight: 900;

                &::after {
                    content: "";
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 2.5px;
                    background: $clr-white;
                    transition: width .3s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<nav id="top-nav" class="top-nav">

        <a href="/index.html" class="top-nav-logo-wrapper">
            <img src="/imgs/pb-logo/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>

        <ul class="top-nav-links">
            <li><a href="/index.html" class="top-nav-link-1">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active-desktop"><a href="#about-section" class="top-nav-link-2">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pp-section" class="top-nav-link-3">Product Party</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact-section" class="top-nav-link-4">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('li > a').click(function () {
        $('li').removeClass();
        $(this).parent().addClass('active-desktop');
    });
```

Comment: @CsCodes, Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery('ul.top-nav-links').scroll(function() {
        $(this).children('li').each(function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset().top;
            if(offset < 0 && offset >= -$(this).height()){
                $('li').removeClass('active-desktop');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active-desktop');
                return false; //"break"
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This isn't working, the about page stays active when I scroll to the next section

Comment: that was an error man, removeClass was called without an argument

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use on scroll event to detect scroll changes & then implement the logic to change active class.

I have created a fiddle for the same below

https://jsfiddle.net/RohanPatil/pytvn264/1/

```
enter code here
```