# ADD/REMOVE classes to individual divs based on scroll, each div has it's own unique class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to use this post: [Add/remove class with jquery based on vertical scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll?noredirect=1)
But can't seem to get it to work with multiple divs, each have their own class and require adding/removing 1 class at different distances from the top.
At a high level here is what I want to happen:

```html
<div class="div-01">1 class added and 1 class removed when user scrolls down 500px from top and reverse if scrolling up</div>
<div class="div-02">1 class added and 1 class removed when user scrolls down 1000px from top and reverse if scrolling up</div> 
<div class="div-03">1 class added and 1 class removed when user scrolls down 1500px from top and reverse if scrolling up</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? It's long form and gross but I haven't written jQuery in a while and I'm simply copying part of the answer that you linked.

**Edit**

I've updated the fiddle you've posted. You can combine the "greater than" and "less than" into one line.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 200 && scroll < 800) {
        $(".div-01").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".div-01").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
    if (scroll >= 1000 && scroll < 1800) {
        $(".div-02").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".div-02").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
    if (scroll >= 2000 && scroll < 2400) {
        $(".div-03").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".div-03").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
});
```

```css
.div-01, .div-02, .div-03 {
  background: red;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
} 

.darkHeader {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-01"></div>
<div class="div-02"></div>
<div class="div-03"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out my problem. Yes the above works with a tweak. I'm passing down the same class from div to div, adding/removing it within a range of vertical scroll. Long story short, here's what I got. https://jsfiddle.net/FunkyMarsH/s2zna4r3/11/

Comment: I'll tweak the answer with what you posted so you can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I included wrong fiddle version previously. Would really like to get the range of pixel scroll in one line like you're suggesting but apparently it needs some tweaks: https://jsfiddle.net/FunkyMarsH/s2zna4r3/14/

Comment: @MarsH The problem was not having the scroll var on the right side of the if statement. I've updated the snippet. Now you're good to go.