# How can I animate or transition CSS when a class is added with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've tried multiple examples but for some reason my CSS just won't animate. `CSS keyframes` worked but I am adding and removing a class to resize a logo when scrolling down. With `keyframes` it resizes to a smaller logo when scrolling down, but jumps immediately back to big when scrolling back up again.

This is my code:

Logo html:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">
    <a class="logolink" href="#"><img src="asset/img/logo-white.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.logolink img').addClass('logo-small');
} else {
    $('.logolink img').removeClass('logo-small');
}
```

And my CSS:

```
.logolink{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo-small{
  max-height:100px;
}
```

I've tried adding `transition: height 2s;` or `transition: max-height 2s;` to `.logo-small` but this doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: add `max-height:0;` in `.logolink`

Comment: Could this post help you out? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll

Comment: @MakisMilas The problem is not adding and removing the class, this works fine. But now it is instant, I would like it to be smooth, transitioning between the small and big size.

Comment: @KunalAwasthi This didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you trying to do ?

```js
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.logolink img').addClass('logo-small');
} else {
    $('.logolink img').removeClass('logo-small');
}
});
```

```css
body{
  height:200vh;
}

.logolink{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
}

.logolink img{
  height:300px;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
}

.logo-small{
  height:100px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">
    <a class="logolink" href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt=""></a>
</div>
```